# Java проверка одинаковых цифр

Tags: java

Привет, всем. Я тут учусь Java и возникла проблема. Я хочу чтоб в случаи если будет два или больше одинаковых цифр в цикле то он мне его показывал.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int b[];
    int c;
    int d=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите размер массива ");
    c = sc.nextInt();
    b = new int[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        b[i] = (int) (Math.random() * c);

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        System.out.println(" " + b[i]);

    for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++)
            if (b[i] > d)
               d = b[i];

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Это самое большое число в массиве: " + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: И если не трудно оставьте ваш комментарий в виде совета по моему коду. Может где что можно упростить или еще что нить))

Comment: Незачем делать 3 цикла, если можно обойтись одним: https://ideone.com/JeZIk9. По вопросу: не очень понятно, что вы хотите. Покажите, какой момент у вас вызывает затруднения, и приведите пример ожидаемого результата

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в консоли появлялась надпись ("в массиве найдено несколько одинаковых самых больших чисел" +d) но в том случаи если они найдены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно это сделать в одно цикле. Заводим счётчик максимальных элементов. Когда появляется новый максимальный, присваиваем ему единицу. Если встречается тот же максимальный, увеличиваем на 1.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int b[];
    int c;
    int d=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите размер массива ");
    c = sc.nextInt();
    b = new int[c];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        b[i] = (int) (Math.random() * c);
        System.out.println(" " + b[i]);
        if (b[i] > d){
               d = b[i];
               count = 1;
        }
        else if (b[i] == d){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (count == 1)
        System.out.println("Это самое большое число в массиве: " + d);
    else
        System.out.println("В массиве найдено несколько (" + count +") одинаковых самых больших чисел " + d);
}
```

Вообще, так как мы всё делаем в одном цикле, запоминать элементы в массив совсем необязательно. Можно генерировать новые числа обрабатывать их и забывать:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int c;
    int d=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите размер массива ");
    c = sc.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        int b = (int) (Math.random() * c);
        System.out.println(" " + b);
        if (b > d){
               d = b;
               count = 1;
        }
        else if (b == d){
            count++;
        }
    }
    // Дальше так же
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понел как это делается.))